# Instagram API vs Instagram Graph API

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'd like to write a really simple website, one that allows ANY Instagram users, big or small, business or personal, to come to my website, login using their instagram credentials (oauth) and then see the last 5 posts on their feed.
I've already done this using the instagram API, but all the documentation says that the API is being deprecated, so I'm looking at moving to the new Graph API. The problem is I'm finding it incredibly confusing.

First of all it seems that the new Graph Api is only for medium or large business accounts. Not for someone with a personal account of a few hundred followers. Is that the case? If it is the case do I need to implement both API's in my app to cater for both large business accounts and small accounts?

If it's not I'm simply looking for an example, using NodeJs or Ruby, of how to complete the oauth flow using the Graph API and then using the access token from the auth flow, hit an endpoint to get that users media.

I already have an app registered on the graph api, I have an app id, secret and have instagram_basic privileges.

Any advice would be very much appreciated,

Thank you,

Craig

Comment: How did you get the app registered on the Insta Graph API? I'm trying to do that but unsure how?

Answer (score 0):

Well here's the message Facebook seems to be sending

From the Graph API site

> If you are building apps for Instagram Non-Business Accounts, please use the Instagram Platform API instead.

From the Instagram Platform API site

> These capabilities will be disabled immediately (previously set for July 31, 2018 or December 11, 2018 deprecation). The following will be deprecated according to the timeline we shared previously:
>
> Public Content - all remaining capabilities to read public media on a user's behalf on December 11, 2018
> Basic - to read a user’s own profile info and media in early 2020
> For your reference, information on the new Instagram Graph API.

I have not had a chance to mess around with Graph API, but if you are interested in going down the old Instagram API route there is documentation that should walk you through getting oauth set up. Once you have an access code for an account it used to be a simple API call to get the last 20 images posted. They broke that last week by introducing CORS issues. I'd be happy to share my work around if it's something you're interested in.

Comment: how long do you think Instagram's old API will keep on running. I use it in a production app with only the basic permissions. The documentation says that it basic permission will be depricated by early 2020 and there are no signs of the same features on the new Graph API. Does that mean that after 2020 I won't be able to get data from the old API or will they only stop providing support for it?